# Error "Application tried to present modal view controller on itself" while activating UISearchController on action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchcontroller

In my code this is how I setup `UISearchController`:

```
searchResultController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(DBSearchResultControllerIdentifier) as! DBSearchResultController

searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)

searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.delegate = self

searchResultController.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

on some action all I do is:

```
@IBAction func cityButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    searchController.active = true
}
```

But then I have an error:

> Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is `UISearchController: 0x7f9a0c04a6a0`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The apple documentation for `UISearchController` clearly says the following things:

- Setting `active` property to YES performs a default presentation of
  the search controller.
- Set the `searchResultsController` parameter to `nil` to display the
  search results in the same view that you are searching.

So it looks like you are using your current view controller itself as your `searchResultsController` and hence when you try to set `active` to YES, it tries to modally present the your current view on itself and hence the error.

Comment: My issue was that I was trying to push the `searchController` on to my `navigationController`. Apparently, I just needed to push my `searchResultController` onto my `navigationController`, and initialize my searchController with `nil`. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know where you found this in the docs, but thanks for sharing.

Comment: Setting `searchController.isActive = false` prior to presenting the VC resolved the issue for me.

Comment: [searchController setActive:NO] did the trick for me. My app was crashing when I tried to dismiss searchController programmatically. This was not a problem until iOS 10.3, but crashes on iOS 11. Instead of dismissing, I simply deactivated the controller. If any of your app is having the same issue just on iOS11, it is worth trying.